# ddply: how to include a character vector in result

Tags: r, plyr

sorry, for the cryptic title i didn't find any better summary for my problem. So here's my problem: i have a dataframe and want to make `diff()` over groups which works fine:

```
 df <- data.frame (name = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 4),
              index = rep(c("c1", "c2"), each=6),
              year = rep(c(2008:2010),4),
              value = rep(1:3, each=4))

head(df)

  name index year value

1    a    c1 2008     1
2    b    c1 2009     1
3    c    c1 2010     1

ddply(df, .(name, year), summarize,  value=diff(value))
```

However, I would like to include the `index` in my result wich i tried to do with:

```
ddply(df, .(name, year), summarize,  value=diff(value), index=index)
```

Yet this yields the error message:

```
length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Which is I guess because the index has more rows because it is not processed by `diff`. Is there a quick solution to my problem?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

I try to clarify my question what I want to add to the result:

Suppose the variable `index` above. This is a factor that ought to explain something. Yet, I cannot take `diff()` of it that would not make sense so I just want to pass this one without changing anything. I tried `drop==FALSE` wich did yield the same error messsage.

Sorr for all this confusion! Here's a very simple example:

```
name year  index  value
 a   2008    c1    10
 a   2009    c2    30
 a   2010    c1    40
```

after taking diff's acroos group 'a' this looks like:

```
name year index d.value 
 a   2009  c2     +20  #c2 stayed the same just the first row got intentionally dropped.
 a   2010  c1     +10
```

consider the unfortunate name `index` as something like an attribute: it can change during the years but would not make sense to take a `diff()`

I really really hope this gives you a clue what I want - if not I'll delete the question because I found an unelegant workaround ;) and sorry for all the inconvenience!

Comment: How do you want to line them up? Head returns the first six elements by default.

Comment: guess i didn't get the meaning of the `head()`part which i copied from another answer. i basically want to pass an index that is strictly tied to name and year but with a higher frequency. i'll clarify my question!

Comment: And what do you want index to look like. One subset in ddply has 4 rows, the diff has three values and the first two have index c1 and second two have index c2. What index value would belong to that? "c1-c2"?

Comment: @Seb, I don't really know what you mean by higher frequency. I suggest you add to your question how you want the index to look like, just by making it manually.

Comment: @Seb, adding the index as such is not possible as the diff returns three values, and the index has 4 values. Adding this index seems problematic because of this...also dropping a c1 or c2 is problematic, because what do you drop. Please add the index you want to see to the result of your first ddply (which does not include the index).

Comment: hi tried to restate it ... dropping is problematic - you're right but dropping only the first line in every group is - for my problem the desired result - the rest of the `index` may stay the same

Comment: `ddply(df, .(name, year, index), summarize, value=diff(value))`?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen that would treat the index as another group and hence draf the `diff()` function in 3 groups instead of two - right? but that's not what I need - or don't i just get the logic?

Comment: Within a `name`/`year` group, is `index` always the same?  If so, Brandon's solution would work because adding this third grouping variable would not change the groups. If not, then there is the problem of identifying which `index` should go with which `diff`-ed value, especially since there is one fewer `diff`-ed values than `index` values.

Comment: @Seb sorry mate, having a bit of difficulty understanding what you're looking for. One thing that could be helpful for potential answerers would be for you to show what you have, and then what you want it to look like (including how the index should be presented after the manipulation). My solution in the form of a question was getting at what Brian mentioned. ie, within-group index similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, it sounded like you want to get diffs, keeping the index variable and dropping the first row of each grouping. Does this get you what you want?

```
doSummary = function(df) {
  values = diff(df$value)
  indexes = df$index[2:length(df)]
  data.frame(d.value=values, index=indexes)
}
ddply(df, .(name, year), doSummary)
```

Comment: it took some time 'till somebody was able to decipher my cryptic explanation but it looks like it was the result i was trying to achieve! thanks a lot!